# Python library for drawing flowcharts and illustrated graphs

Tags: python, graph

Is there a Python library to draw flowcharts and illustrated graphs like these?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 10):

You can use Schemdraw. Though it's main purpose is producing high-quality electrical circuit schematic diagrams, there is a part of the package that can be used to draw flowcharts.

For example:
https://schemdraw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gallery/flowcharting.html#galleryflow

[image]

Comment: Schemdraw creates beautiful charts... but you need to explicitly control the layout of the diagram, which is time consuming and frustrating.

Answer (score 7):

[Network Charts](https://python-graph-gallery.com/network-chart/) might do the trick.  Check out the [Networkx docs](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/index.html) for more detailed info.  This too is designed for large networks, but it can be customized a bit to serve as a flow chart if you combine a few of there examples.  I was able to create this with a little digging, which can serve as a decent template for a flow chart.

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize = (12,9))

From = ['Food\nProduction', 'Transportation', 'Energy\nProduction',
        "Greenhouse\nGas\nEmissions",'Climate\nChange','Climate\nFeedbacks','Greenhouse\nGas\nEmissions',
        'Climate\nChange']
To = ["Greenhouse\nGas\nEmissions", "Greenhouse\nGas\nEmissions",
      "Greenhouse\nGas\nEmissions",'Climate\nChange','Climate\nFeedbacks','Greenhouse\nGas\nEmissions',
      'Climate\nChange','Everyone$^{Dies}$']

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'from':From,
                   'to':To})
# Define Node Positions
pos = {'Food\nProduction':(1,1),
        'Transportation':(1,2),
        'Energy\nProduction':(1,3),
        'Greenhouse\nGas\nEmissions':(2,2),
        'Climate\nChange':(3,2),
        'Climate\nFeedbacks':(2.5,3),
        'Everyone$^{Dies}$':(4,2)}

# Define Node Colors
NodeColors = {'Food\nProduction':[1,0,1],
        'Transportation':[1,1,0],
        'Energy\nProduction':[0,1,1],
        'Greenhouse\nGas\nEmissions':[1,.5,1],
        'Climate\nChange':[0,1,0],
        'Climate\nFeedbacks':[0,0,1],
        'Everyone$^{Dies}$':[1,0,0]}

Labels = {}
i = 0
for a in From:
    Labels[a]=a
    i +=1
Labels[To[-1]]=To[-1]

# Build your graph. Note that we use the DiGraph function to create the graph! This adds arrows
G=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'from', 'to', create_using=nx.DiGraph() )

# Define the colormap and set nodes to circles, but the last one to a triangle
Circles = []
Traingle = []
Colors_Circles = []
Colors_Traingle = []
for n in G.nodes:
    if n != 'Everyone$^{Dies}$':
        Circles.append(n)
        Colors_Circles.append(NodeColors[n])
    else:
        Traingle.append(n)
        Colors_Traingle.append(NodeColors[n])

# By making a white node that is larger, I can make the arrow "start" beyond the node
nodes = nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, 
                       nodelist = Circles,
                       node_size=1.25e4,
                       node_shape='o',
                       node_color='white',
                       alpha=1)

nodes = nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, 
                       nodelist = Circles,
                       node_size=1e4,
                       node_shape='o',
                       node_color=Colors_Circles,
                       edgecolors='black',
                       alpha=0.5)


nodes = nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, 
                       nodelist = Traingle,
                       node_size=1.25e4,
                       node_shape='>',
                       node_color='white',
                       alpha=1)

nodes = nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, 
                       nodelist = Traingle,
                       node_size=1e4,
                       node_shape='>',
                       node_color=Colors_Traingle,
                       edgecolors='black',
                       alpha=0.5)


nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, Labels, font_size=12)

# Again by making the node_size larer, I can have the arrows end before they actually hit the node
edges = nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, node_size=1.8e4,
                               arrowstyle='->',width=2,arrowsizes=10)

plt.xlim(0,4.5)
plt.ylim(0,4)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks June. I think `node_color=Colors` is throwing a Value error at me telling me that the RGBA conversion failed: `'c' argument has 7 elements, which is not acceptable for use with 'x' with size 6, 'y' with size 6.` What can I do to get around that? Thanks.

Comment: @BowenLiu I fixed it.  Changed it to define separate color lists for the circles vs triangels

Comment: Thanks June! It indeed works right now. I am tweaking what you have to achieve something similar. I wonder, could you make it work if one of the `to` column cells is null? Can there be a standalone node in the chart. Here is the link to my question if you are interested:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67308865/from-a-pandas-dataframe-build-networkx-chart-or-flow-chart-between-different-ro

Comment: @JuneSkeeter, amazing solution, will adopt it for my purpose!
And there is tiny typo: arrowsizes should be in singular arrowsize in draw_networkx_edges :)

Answer (score 1):

You might like to try PyDot:
https://code.google.com/p/pydot/

I haven't tried the python version, but I have used Graphviz in the past and it's pretty good.

Comment: I know graphviz, but the images in its gallery [http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery.php] are really ugly, and does not support latex (?). It should be designed for large network graphs, not for illustration graphs.