# How to create a dynamic flowchart using python and socketio in python to track code running process?

Tags: python, graphviz, flask-socketio, flowchart, python-socketio

So the goal is to monitor our code running procedure.
For example, in our codes, we have step 1 loading the data, step 2 processing the data, step3...

We want to plot out this procedure in flowchart on a web page. But at the same time we want the flow chart to by dynamic so that when step 1 is done if will turn red and then step2, step 3.

I've done a lot of researching and saw we can do socketio for real-time communication between the server and client and then graphviz for flowchart plotting. But it's just an idea I don't know how to implement it. Does anyone know if there's any project source that I can take a look at or there's a better way of handling this problem? We want a python backend server and either python or js client front end.

[image: Flowchart example]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python library for drawing flowcharts and illustrated graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22920433/python-library-for-drawing-flowcharts-and-illustrated-graphs)